# Projection $\operatorname{Spec}(K[x,y]) \rightarrow \operatorname{Spec}(K[x])$ not closed

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials

Let $K$ be a field. I am trying to show that the map $\operatorname{Spec}(K[x,y]) \rightarrow \operatorname{Spec}(K[x])$ induced by the inclusion $K[x] \hookrightarrow K[x,y]$ is not closed (topologically). My "geometric" idea was to show that the image of $V(xy-1) \subseteq \operatorname{Spec}(K[x,y])$ is exactly $\operatorname{Spec}(K[x]) \setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace$ which is not closed. This comes from the intuition that this map "is the projection $\mathbb{A}_K^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{A}_K$", but I do not know how to show this rigurously.

Comment: Please add the context of this problem, i.e. where you got this problem from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track.

To look at the image of $V(xy-1)$ under the projection, consider the composite morphism $\operatorname{Spec} k[x,y]/(xy-1) \to \operatorname{Spec} k[x,y] \to \operatorname{Spec} k[x]$, which corresponds to the ring morphism $k[x]\to k[x,y]/(xy-1)$ by $x\mapsto x$. To show that this map is not closed, we can show that it has nonclosed image.

The closed subsets of $\operatorname{Spec} k[x]$ are the empty set, the entire space, and finite unions of closed points. Since $k[x,y]/(xy-1)$ is integral, $\operatorname{Spec} k[x,y]/(xy-1)$ is irreducible; combining this with the fact that the image of an irreducible topological space is irreducible, we see that the if the image of $\operatorname{Spec} k[x,y]/(xy-1)$ in $\operatorname{Spec} k[x]$ is closed, it can only be the whole space or a single closed point.

It cannot be the whole space: there is nothing that maps to $(x)$, as $k[x,y]/(xy-1)\otimes_{k[x]} k[x]/(x) = 0$.

It cannot be a single closed point: the generic point is in the image (look at the zero ideal).

Thus this map is not closed.

Comment: Thanks! This shows that the image is not closed, but how do we show that the image is exactly $Spec(K[x]) \setminus {0} $ ?

Comment: Idea: Perhaps computing the fibers as we did with $(x)$?

Comment: I am not sure how to show that when $\mathfrak{p} \neq 0$ then the tensor product is nonzero, though.

Comment: The ring map $k[x]\to k[x,y]/(xy-1)$ must factor through the localization $k[x]_x$ since $x$ is invertible in the target. But $k[x]_x\cong k[x,y]/(xy-1)$, so the image is exactly $\operatorname{Spec} k[x] \setminus 0$. (Side note: you probably want to say $\mathfrak{p}\neq(x)$, not $\mathfrak{p}\neq 0$ in that last comment.)

Comment: Oh yes, I meant $\mathfrak{p} \neq (x) $ , sorry. Where does that isomorphism $k[x]_{(x)} \cong k[x,y]/(xy-1)$ come from?

Comment: Well, $xy=1$, so $y=x^{-1}$. It shouldn't be that hard to verify yourself, and if you run in to trouble I'm sure it's been posted here on MSE before.

Comment: I have the intuition now. Everything clear. Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

Denote the induced function $\operatorname{Spec}(K[x,y]) \to \operatorname{Spec}(K[x])$ by $\pi$. Two steps:

1. What is $\pi\big((xy-1)K[x,y]\big)$? This should tell you immediately what the image of $V(xy-1)$ must be if it is to be closed.
2. Why is $xK[x]$ (the maximal ideal which corresponds to the point $0$ in $\mathbb A_K$) not in the image $\pi\big(V(xy-1)\big)$? This is actually really easy: what is $x K[x,y] + (xy-1)K[x,y]$?